# Toggle inline style background-color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle on/off the inline background color of some table cells. The HTML table is dynamically created so I may not add any class. It has its own CSS but some TDs have also inline style. I would like to toggle these inline styles on/off so that users may choose between the CSS styles or the inline styles. Cells may have different inline background colors.

I can select the TDs that have the inline style like this:

```
$('.tbl_container td[style*="background-color"]');
```

But if I try something like this it removes the inline background but it doesn't restore it:

```
$('.tbl_container td[style*="background-color"]').toggle(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '');
});
```

I guess I have to use `hide()` but I don't know how.

Comment: Use classes. Targetting by style as you are doing seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: `this.style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor ? "" : this.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: @Mr_Green Kindly expand your code. I'm not so good with JQuery. Please note as remarked about the answer below that the value of bg becomes 'undefined' after the background is removed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `class` names for these purposes.

```
.color{
background-color: blue;
}

.color2{
background-color: white;
}
```

Then in `jQuery` you can do like this

```
$('.That_particular_td').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).attr('class')== 'color'){
        $(this).attr('class','color2');
    }
    else if($(this).attr('class')== 'color2'){
       $(this).attr('class','color');
    }
});
```

**NOTE:**

You can use the **[jQuery On()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** method for dynamically created HTML Elements

Comment: As said the table is dynamically created I may not add a class

Comment: @Nicero This seems irrelevant?

Comment: Check out the edit, you can use jQuery's on() method for dynamically generated html elements

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS odd and even selector for table row. More easy and without javascript/jquery.

More description use below link.

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html